# How to embed time picker in view

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I've integrated `TimePicker` in my application successfully. Now i would like to know is there a way to embed time picker in view instead of showing it as Dialog box. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you , it is good habit to use fragment.if you use the DialogFragment ,google provide using the dialog frament for time picker http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePicker

or

I found some link it can help you
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/timepicker/android-time-picker-example/

Comment: Thank you @Virendra, your second link has provided some good information. To embed timepicker in view all we need to do is use this tag.

<TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Answer (score 2):

Actually showing in a `DialogFragment` is considered best practice. Still if you want to create similar view in your layout then I guess your best bet would be using `wheel-view` to achieve this.

Here is a library for it: https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ and its other implementation: https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel

In case you want to stick with `DialogFragment`(recommended), here is a tutorial: http://androidician.wordpress.com/2014/09/20/android-date-picker-and-time-picker-example/